# O uso e não uso da palavra function no TypeScript

Tags: funções, typescript, método

Por que quando declaro método em uma classe o compilador apita, informando que esta errado o uso da palavra `function`.

Em lições anteriores do meu aprendizado para criar uma função assinava primeiramente como `function`.

```
abstract class Empregado {    
    abstract getFuncao():string;
}

class Professor extends Empregado {
    getFuncao():string {
        return "Professor";
    }
}

class Diretor extends Empregado {
    getFuncao():string {
        return "Diretor";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta já está na pergunta.

Porque você não declara funções dentro de uma classe, declara métodos, então não faria sentido usar `function`. Além do que dentro de uma classe o compilador tem mais controle do que está acontecendo (a sintaxe é menos ambígua) e pode determinar o início e fim do método, por exemplo não pode ter uma método dentro de outro, mas é possível ter uma função dentro de um método.

Comment: Interessante! Como vc mencionou, eu respondi, mas foi uma curiosidade, ou seja, function é mais para `scripts` a nível procedural.

Comment: @Macario1983 Isso